# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel not showing up even though I installed it

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio

I installed Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel in Visual Studio:

[image: Screen shot showing it's installed]

But when I try to add the reference, it does not show up:

[image: Screen shot searching references to add]

Comment: What type of project did you add it to?  Have you tried putting a using statement at the top? ... `using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;`

Comment: I agree with Skin… the first picture shows that it IS installed. Have you tried adding the using statement in your code?

Comment: Interesting, I put using 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel' at the top, and there was no error. So I guess it just automatically added the reference when I installed it? Still not sure why the reference doesn't show up when I try to add it. But I guess it will work.

Comment: When adding via Nuget, you don't need to worry about the references.  It's implicit.